# zope.deprectation: solve import issues with pydev, .pth files and site-packages

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pyramid

I'm using python 3.4.2 in a virtual environment. I've setup pydev to use my virtual environment interpreter with the virtual environment's site-packages directory.

Everything is fine from the command line when I run the virtual environment's version of python. I can import everything correctly.

However, sometimes I have issues inside PyDev even though it's configured for the virtual environment.

One big issue I am having is PyDev is not seeing zope.deprecation. This is likely due to the fact that in site-packages, the zope directory does not have a **init**.py file. In fact creating this file makes PyDev see zope.deprecation.

In the site-packages directory the zope.deprecation package does come with zope.deprecation-4.1.1-py3.4-nspkg.pth and zope.deprecation-4.1.1-py3.4.egg-info which I assume are supposed to aid in setting up things correctly.

But PyDev doesn't seem to understand.

(I have a similar problem with the newrelic...it's directory structure under site-packages is not 'canoncial' but it also comes with a .pth file to help the interpreter understand where to find things).

My question is how do I get PyDev to understand the site-packages environment correctly?

Manually touching a **init**.py is completely hacky...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyDev does not support namespace packages. Here is bug report https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/151

By the way, PyCharm (great Python IDE) does [support](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/whatsnew_26.html) namespace packages since 2012 –

> PyCharm has been updated to support the new language features of
>   Python 3.3, including the new namespace packages.

Comment: Great, thank you, good to know I'm not losing my mind. I've heard lots of great things about PyCharm. If I continue doing lots of Python dev I may switch over. I've heard it suffers from slowness though...at least it's worth checking out though!